# Export tensorflow model to ONNX and specify variable names

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, onnx, tf2onnx

I have a tensorflow model written through model subclassing and I want to export it to ONNX format. This is simple enough with the script attached. However, the name of the input variable to the ONNX model is `args_0`. How can I rename it?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tf2onnx
from tensorflow.python.keras import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense


class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.dense = Dense(16)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        return self.dense(inputs)

    def to_onnx(self, output_path, opset=14):
        model_proto, _ = tf2onnx.convert.from_keras(
            self,
            input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec((1, 128))],
            opset=opset,
            output_path=output_path,
        )
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    output_path = "./test.onnx"
    A = MyModel()
    A.to_onnx(output_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can provide the input name in `input_signature` as `name="input_name"` so, it should look like

```
 input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec((1, 128), name="input_name")],
```

as shown in [this](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx/blob/82812543c22e1318ca1ffa4e5431830c17d16d29/tutorials/huggingface-bert.ipynb) notebook

Comment: Would you by any chance know how to rename the outputs as well?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an option for [that](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx#python-api-reference)

Comment: Actually, despite what I said before, there's a typo in your answer: the name should be inside the TensorSpec. I didn't notice at first because I wrote it correctly on my machine when copying it! XD

Comment: yes my bad edited ans

Comment: Hi. Is there a way to provide output signature as well? the following param didn't work: output_signature